# How to fix "Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'"?

Tags: reactjs, particles.js

I'm trying to get particlesjs to run in react. But that doesn't seem to work..So , I tried using react-particles-js .But it gives me this error:
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users\Amit\node_modules\particles-js\lib'

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';

        import ParticleAnimation from 'particles-js';

         class Example extends Component {
            render () {
               return (
              <ParticleAnimation />
          )
        }
       }export default Example;
```

I've been trying to mess with the file path in the import statement but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Did you install react as a dependency? `npm i --save react`

Comment: Yeah that was the problem..Thanks

Comment: Also, before asking a question do a little research. That question was answered tens of times before both on StackOverflow or Github threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to install it again in you project ,

> yarn add react

or

> npm i react --save

Comment: it's my pleasure to help you @amitkumar