# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react '

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial and all of a sudden I am getting this error. I have tried all the solution I could find but no success

./src/Components/Views/Dashboard/Notification.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react ' in 'C:\Users....\Dashboard'

I have tried these solutions :
[How to fix "Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416988/how-to-fix-module-not-found-cant-resolve-react)

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2534

Dashboard.js

```
  import React, { Component} from 'react'
  import Notifications from './Notification'
  import ProjectList from '../Projects/ProjectList'

   class Dashboard extends Component {
     render() {
        return(
               <div className="dasboard container">
                    <div className="row">
                          <div className="col s12 m6">
                                <ProjectList />
                          </div>
                          <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                                <Notifications />

                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
             )
       }
   }
```

Notification.js

```
  import React from 'react '

  const Notifications = () => {
    return(
          <div className="container">
                <p>Nostifications</p>
          </div>
      )
   } 

   export default Notifications
```

Comment: this might not help but you have a few typos. I'm not sure if its just from posting it on SO but

Comment: is there an extra space after react in Notification.js?

Comment: Have you actually installed React?

Comment: yeah react was installed and everything was working just fine. before the error.
@Michael Cacciano's solution help.

Answer (score 1):

this might not help but you have a few typos. I'm not sure if its just from posting it on SO but try this

Dashboard.js

```
  import React, { Component} from 'react'
  import Notifications from './Notification' // Notification that you're importing isnt the same as the import name - Notifications from Notifications not Notification
  import ProjectList from '../Projects/ProjectList'

   class Dashboard extends Component {
     render() {
        return(
               <div className="dasboard container">
                    <div className="row">
                          <div className="col s12 m6">
                                <ProjectList />
                          </div>
                          <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                                <Notifications />

                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
             )
       }
   }
```

Notification.js

```
import React from 'react ' // <- there is a space here after the react import try taking it out

  const Notifications = () => {
    return(
          <div className="container">
                <p>Nostifications</p>
          </div>
      )
   } 

   export default Notifications
```

Comment: No problem at all. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer since it helped you get by it and happy coding :D